# porque responsive desing no me funciona?

Tags: html, css

soy novato en lo de la programacion, y he estado haciendo un proyecto, que es una calculadora, y pues ultimamente me he dedicado a tratar de solucionar un error que la verdad no he podido arreglar, y por eso no les puedo dar una linea de codigo de error, porque no se donde esta el problema, y es que basicamente yo al hacer el responsive design y mirar que tal esta quedando, desde el computador con lo de agrandar o empequeñeser la pagina todo va de maravilla, desde lo mas grande hasta lo mas chico, hasta miro en paginas externas y me dicen que la pagina esta optimizada para movil, pero cuando la miro en mi celular el contenido es mas ancho que la pantalla, osea que se ve como si fuese de ordenador pero en celular, cuando miro en otro celular mas antiguo esta mejor optimizado pero no queda como me muestra en las pruebas que hago, si me pueden ayudar lo agradeceria y me disculpo de antemano mi forma tosca de preguntar y mi mala ortografia

estos son los links de mi pagina y de las pruebas que le hago:
https://revelcalc.com
https://revelcalc.com/hallartriangulo.html

pruebas
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revelcalc.com%2Fhallartriangulo.html

https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly?utm_source=gws&utm_medium=metaline&utm_campaign=notmobilefriendy&url=https%3A%2F%2Frevelcalc.com%2Fhallartriangulo.html

Comment: Sugiero que incluyas el código de un [mcve] en tu pregunta, eso aumentará tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no estás usando flexbox o algo similar, los elementos del diseño deberían estar en cajas de flexbox para que se readapten al tamaño de la pantalla. Te dejo un enlace a la documentación de flexbox, es muy sencillo para lo que quieres hacer. Suerte y animo.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp